# Are Whois websites trustable?

Tags: domains, domain-registrar

A good domain name is counted a precious property. There are some websites which offer the WHOIS service to check the availability of a domain name, like who.is, or whois.com, ...

Are they just offer this service and don't care to the entered names or could it be possible that they probe the names to get inspired by them and register some domains for themselves?

Comment: You have nothing to worry about. The various whois websites are automated and the people who run them just want to sell ad space and services. They are not into domain monetizing and have historically stayed out of that fray. In the early days, Network Solutions sold real-time access to it's search queries to domain monetization investors and caught holy hell for it. Since then, no one has dared to cross that line. It was dirty pool then it is dirty pool now.

Comment: I find it is easier to check domain availability on registrar sites than on whois sites. For example, the Namecheap interface is fast and easy to use plus it includes all of the new TLDs.

Answer (score 2):

WHOIS is actually a protocol. Various websites and tools can use this particular protocol to find out about the availability of a domain name. And yes, most of these websites are trustworthy, simply because they don't have much to gain from you. Why would they need your input to inspire them about the importance of a particular domain name? A vast number of websites and software applications (in general) have the ability to look up WHOIS information. What's to stop them from programatically looking up domain names based on common dictionary words and popular phrases? Besides: Most of the valuable keyword-based domain names are taken. Valuable domain names relating to new words, names and key phrases are quickly sold. I think you're being overly-cautious :)

Comment: Thank you, however there is a difference between a random mix of words generated by  a software and words which could be used for or inspire a new business. For example *doc2pdf* maybe is not easily generated by a software but it is valuable for a business.